# How to insert with POPUP LoV value that doesnt exist in table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to insert into tags table only value that doesn't exist in table.
For that field I use POPUP LoV which has enable: Manual Entry, Multi Value, Search as Youtube.
I tried with application process and function which is execute only on submit form page, which doesn't work properly.
function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION check_ins_tags  (p_name VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
 count_res number := 0;
BEGIN

SELECT count(name)
INTO count_res
from tags
where upper(name) = upper(p_name);

IF count_res < 1 THEN


insert into tags (name)
select regexp_substr(p_name, '[^:]+', 1, level) 
from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(p_name, ',') + 1;


ELSE
 NULL;

END IF;

RETURN count_res;

EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 NULL;

END;
```

POPUP can have multi value, I need to check for that values separately, and them insert if that value is not in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, that's a wrong approach. Functions shouldn't be *inserting* anything - use **procedures** for such a purpose.

Also, the whole code you posted can be substituted by a single `MERGE` statement. Here's how.

Sample table; initially, it contains `BMW`:

```
SQL> create table tags (name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into tags (name) values ('BMW');

1 row created.
```

As I use SQL*Plus for this demonstration, I'm using a substitution variable which simulates your multi-select Pop-up list of values item. Presume it contains three names, one of which is `BMW` so it shouldn't be inserted again - that's what `MERGE`'s `WHEN` clause does:

```
SQL> merge into tags t
  2    using (select regexp_substr('&&P1_POPUP', '[^:]+', 1, level) name
  3           from dual
  4           connect by level <= regexp_count('&&P1_POPUP', ':') + 1
  5          ) x
  6    on (x.name = t.name)
  7    when not matched then insert (name) values (x.name);
Enter value for p1_popup: Ford:BMW:Mercedes

2 rows merged.
```

What does the table contain now?

```
SQL> select * from tags;

NAME
--------------------
BMW
Mercedes
Ford

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me.

---

As you use Apex, your `merge` would then be

```
merge into tags t
  using (select regexp_substr(:P1_POPUP, '[^:]+', 1, level) name
         from dual
         connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_POPUP, ':') + 1
        ) x
  on (x.name = t.name)        
  when not matched then insert (name) values (x.name);
```

Comment: Can I use ', '  as separator instead of ':' in connect by?

Comment: No, not in this context because Apex separates values from multi-select items by a colon (`:`). But, generally speaking, yes - you can use any separator you want.